# How to access keys and values from Array of object stored in localstorage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I am working on a shopping cart in asp.net web pages. I stored product information in an array in form of object and save in `localStorage` when the user clicks on add to cart button.and want to access that information on cart page. onclick event on add to cart button call a function and send three values to javascript as a parameter like this.

```
onclick="Add('@Row.P_ID','@Row.P_Name','@Row.P_Price')"
```

Here is My Html code for product.

```
<div class="row">
                        @foreach (var Row in db.Query(slctquery))
                        {
                           var pid = Row.P_ID;
                             <div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                  <img src="@Url.Content(Row.P_Image)" alt="Product Image" style="height:200px;">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <h3>@Row.P_Name</h3>
                                        <p style="font-size:large" id="UPrice">@Row.P_Price</p>
                                        <p><a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetail","Home",new{pid=pid})" class="btn btn-info" role="button">View Detail</a>
<a onclick="Add('@Row.P_ID','@Row.P_Name','@Row.P_Price')" id="'@Row.P_ID'" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Add to Cart</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }      
                    </div><!-- End row -->
```

My javascript code is:

```
<script>
var Cart=[];
function Add(id,name,price)
{
    var item={
        Pid:id,
        PNme:name,
        Price:price,
        quantity:'1'
    };
    var Cartitem = JSON.stringify(item);
    Cart.push(Cartitem); 
   window.localStorage.setItem("Cart",JSON.stringify(Cart));
}
```

it is working well and data stored in localstorage..but i want to acces these objects properties (key and value) like Pids and PNme on shopping cart html table in rows.
Cart page javascript is:

```
 var cartitem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Cart"));
    alert(cartitem);
```

View where i want to add these values..
[Shopping Cart table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYaSL.png)
How Can i do this...
..(sorry For Bad English)

Comment: could you share more details about your requirement?

Comment: Sir I Want to Access Objects values and want to add each object's values as a row in table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse items of array being result of `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Cart"))`:

```
var cartitem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Cart")).map(JSON.parse);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var cartitem=JSON.parse(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("Cart")));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, I hope it will meet your requirement**

```
var cartitem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Cart"));
var i=0, len = cartitem.length;
var dbArray = [], tmpArr = [];
for(;i<len;i++){
   tmpArr.push(cartitem[i].Pid);
   tmpArr.push(cartitem[i].PNme);
   tmpArr.push(cartitem[i].Price);
   tmpArr.push(cartitem[i].quantity);
   dbArray.push(tmpArr);
   tmpArr = [];
}

console.log("Final Db ready Array of records");
console.log(dbArray);

output will be : 
[
   ["abc1", "New Suite", "40400", "1"],
   ["abc2", "New Suite2", "2547", "1"],
   ["abc3", "New Suite3", "100", "8"],
   ["abc4", "New Suite4", "8500", "6"],
   ["abc5", "New Suite5", "10000", "2"],
   ["abc6", "New Suite6", "32000", "1"],
]
```